# Swift: How to filter in Core Data

Tags: swift, core-data

I'm using the following code to fetch all the data in "category".

```
let appDelegate = UIApplication.sharedApplication().delegate as AppDelegate

let managedContext = appDelegate.managedObjectContext!
let fetchRequest = NSFetchRequest(entityName:"category")
let fetchedResults = managedContext.executeFetchRequest(fetchRequest, error: &error) as [NSManagedObject]?
```

How do I only brings categories where the "type" is equal to "products"?

Comment: Look into NSPredicate

Answer (score 38, accepted):

To "filter" results in Core Data, use `NSPredicate` like so:

```
let filter = "products"
let predicate = NSPredicate(format: "type = %@", filter)
fetchRequest.predicate = predicate
```

Comment: just what I was looking for, perfect :), worked for me.

Comment: What is the type = %@ for? What does it do?

Comment: "type = %@" is an object on which filtration will be performed.

Answer (score 2):

So, in the below example

1. In the first step, we will add give the value we want to filter.
2. In the second step, we will add a predicate in which we will give the DB key we want to get the value in my case is "id" and besides this a value, we want to filter.
3. In the Third step assign the entity name where your all data has saved in the NSFetchRequest.
4. After that assign the predicate.
5. Use context object to fetch the object.

```swift
private let context = (NSApplication.shared.delegate as! AppDelegate).persistentContainer.viewContext
        
let filter = id
let predicate = NSPredicate(format: "id = %@", filter)
let fetchRequest = NSFetchRequest<NSFetchRequestResult>(entityName:"TodoListItem")
fetchRequest.predicate = predicate
                    
do{
    let fetchedResults = try context.fetch(fetchRequest) as! [NSManagedObject]
    print("Fetch results")
    if  let task = fetchedResults.first as? TodoListItem{
        print(task)
    }
                      
    //  try context.save()
            
}catch let err{
    print("Error in updating",err)
}
```

Comment: thanks a lot it worked for me after some changes

Answer (score 0):

You can use .filter on the fetchedResults.

Comment: Yes you can, but that's a Swift function. Using NSDelegate delegates filtering to Core Data which *can* be more efficient, especially on large data sets.

Comment: I feel like that should be changed to *is* more efficient. It uses less memory and big O is n instead of 2n