# How to filter data using coreData

Tags: ios, core-data, filter, swift3, nsfetchedresultscontroller

I want to know how to filter data while using a searchBar. Lets say I have 300 friend objects and I want to find a specific friend named "Rick" in my tableView. While searching, I would like to filter my friends every time a character is enter. So if I type in a **R** in search bar all names starting with r shows. Then when I type in an **I** it filters all names starting with **RI** and so on.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Swift: How to filter in Core Data](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28754959/swift-how-to-filter-in-core-data)

Comment: https://developer.apple.com/reference/foundation/nspredicate

Comment: Luis this is not a tutorial site. You should attempt to learn what is required to code a solution to your problem and only ask a question if you are really "stuck" and unable to work out a solution. There is an enormous amount of information on the internet (and SO) that will help you learn how to filter data while using a search bar.

Answer (score 1):

One way of filtering core data fetches is by using predicates. You could do something like this:

```
let fetchPredicate: NSPredicate = NSPredicate(format: "whichever property you are fetching = %@", Your textfield.text)
        fetchRequest.predicate = fetchPredicate
```

You may have to trick it a bit around to make it fit to your needs, but that is one way of sorting your fetches in core data.